# Getting leaves' stem to stick out of the branch with Unity's tree creator

Tags: unity

I am using unity's tree creator to create... well you can guess.

However the leaves' stem doesn't exactly stick out of the branch...

[image]

I've tried to play with parameters like `Growth angle`, `Geometry mode`, `Perpendicular align`, and `Horizontal align`, but non of them guarantee that the leaf stem is properly placed. The stem itself is at the very bottom of the image I used for the material of the leaves...